# Command line java yields different result than IntelliJ

Tags: java

I am learning Java and one of the exercises instructs to run the program from the command line instead in the IDE.

In the IDE the result is 143260 words, but from the command line the result is 1397.  What am I doing wrong here?

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        File file = new File("taleoftwocities.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int words = 0;
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            words += line.split(" ").length;
        }
        System.out.println("The file contains: " + words + " words.");
    }
}
```

Comment: this should not cause a difference. can you add a print statement to print the (complete) path of file? maybe you are not reading the same file

Comment: I added a print statement to get the path and confirmed I am reading the correct file.  I added a line by line print also to see what it was reading and it turns out it stops reading in the middle of a word and exits the while loop.  I am not sure why it only does this from CMD.

Comment: is the default encoding different in your IDE?

Comment: The encoding reported in the IDE is UTF-8 and in the CMD it reports Windows-1252.  Am I supposed to set the file Scanner stream to something specific so that it works in CMD and IDE the same?  It seems odd to me that a plain text file would be handled differently in the IDE (which is running in Windows) than it would be in the Windows CMD environment.